# Using Regex to capture text after the last Instance of a word

Tags: regex, perl

New to regex and I have a file with data that looks like this

```
[Monkey]
KeyValue=B233

[Monkey]
KeyValue=A421

[Monkey]
KeyValue=Z123

[Monkey]
KeyValue=C84
```

originally I was using

```
KeyValue=(.*)
```

to capture everything after the equal sign.   But now I need the value after the last occurrence of `KeyValue=`

How would this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using negative lookahead assertion:

```
KeyValue=(\w+)(?![\s\S]*KeyValue)
```

You can replace `[\s\S]` with `.` if you use `DOTALL` flag.

[Demo in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lV7iF3/1)

---

```
my $text = <<EOS;
[Monkey]
KeyValue=B233

[Monkey]
KeyValue=A421

[Monkey]
KeyValue=Z123

[Monkey]
KeyValue=C84
OtherValue=XYZ
EOS

$text =~ /KeyValue=(\w+)(?!.*KeyValue)/s;
print $1;
```

Comment: This worked.  But how do I extract the match group that comes after the = sign ?

Comment: @Alex, Use capturing group as you did in the question code. If you let me know which language / regular expression engine you are using, I can give you example.

Comment: It's in Perl.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Alex, I updated the answer with an example perl code. ([ideone demo](http://ideone.com/73rMMX)]

Answer (score 1):

Add an anchor to your regex

```
KeyValue=.*$
```

[**Regex Example**](https://regex101.com/r/aQ5rO1/1)

- `$` anchors the regex at the end of the string. Ensures that nothing follows